# Obtain residual standard errors of an "mlm" object returned by `lm()`

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, mlm

I've used `lm()` to fit multiple regression models, for multiple (~1 million) response variables in R. Eg.

```
allModels <- lm(t(responseVariablesMatrix ~ modelMatrix)
```

This returns an object of class "mlm", which is like a huge object containing all the models. I want to get the Residual Sum of Squares for each model, which I can do using:

```
summaries <- summary(allModels)
rss1s <- sapply(summaries, function(a) return(a$sigma))
```

My problem is that I think the "summary" function calculates a whole bunch of other stuff, too, and is hence quite slow. I'm wondering if there is a faster way of extracting just the Residual sum of squares for the model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a component residuals in output of `lm` object, so you get residual sum of squares by `sum(output$residuals^2)`.

edit: You are actually taking sigma out of summaries, which is 
`sqrt(sum(output$residuals^2)/output$df.residuals)`

For all models use

`sapply(allModels, function(a) sqrt(sum(a$residuals^2)/a$df.residuals)))`

Answer (score 0):

Rarely known to many, the generic function `deviance` can compute residual sum of squares for "lm" and "mlm" models. Let `fit` be your fitted model, you can do

```
sqrt(deviance(fit) / fit$df.residual)
```

There are two advantages here:

1. the generic function is fully "vectorized" (using `colSums`) rather than loop-based (like the solution via `sapply`);
2. the generic function knows how to deal with weighted regression case.